# How to find the percentage of marks using 2D arrays in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get inputs such as roll no and obtained marks 5 times in sequence. The program will get 5 roll no first then take 5 obtained marks input. lastly, calculate the percentage of obtained marks. But this program stops after taking 5 roll numbers... looking for answer Thank you!

```
public static void main (String[] args){

         percent();
}
public static void percent(){

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int perc;
    int total=0;
    int studentlist[][];
    studentlist = new int [5][5];

     for (int[] markArray : studentlist){

         System.err.println("Student roll no:");
         markArray[0] =scan.nextInt();


         for (int j = 1; j< markArray.length;j++){

            System.out.println("Enter Obtained marks:");
            markArray[j]=scan.nextInt();
            total = total+ markArray[j];

         }
       }
        perc= ((total/550)*100);
        System.out.println("Percentage:"+ perc);   
}
```

Comment: dose your program faced with exception ?

Comment: no exceptions its just stops after taking 5 roll numbers. which has to execute whole program thank you for reply.